# Printing excess decimal places in python

Tags: python, format, numbers, decimalformat

I run the following code:

```
numero = 80.12
a = int(numero)
b = abs(numero) - abs(int(numero))
print(a,b)
```

And as a result I get...

```
80, 0.12000000000000455
```

I don't know what could be the problem of printing excess of decimal places.

Comment: It's a floating point number, they are imprecise by definition

Answer (score 1):

The full gory details can be found in this [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).  Floating point representations of decimal fractions are almost never precise.